# OpenLayers: how to add dynamic markers onClick with Longitude and Latitude?

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers

Currently working on a map for an interface where users click on a map to get their longitude and latitude. So far I have managed to get the lon and lat data and have it input in the form, but having difficulties displaying a marker where the user has clicked, and removing it when the user clicks on a new location. any ideas?

this is my function:

initLocationPicker: function (){

```
    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            })
        ],

        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            center: [13.4050,52.5200],
            zoom: 2
        })
    });

    var formId = this.formId;
    var form = document.forms[formId];


    map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {

        var lonlat = ol.proj.transform(evt.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
        var lon = lonlat[0];
        var lat = lonlat[1];
        console.log(lonlat);

        form.elements.longitude.value = lon
        form.elements.latitude.value = lat

    });
},
```

I hope this snippet helps, otherwise i'll try and add a jsfiddle.

Comment: See https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/popup.html

Comment: How are you trying to add the marker?  I don't see any attempt in the posted code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Mike! this would be an option, but a simple marker/pin would be more ideal! already have a function to display lon/lat in a form.

Comment: @geocodezip I removed the code to add the marker as it was messing up the rest of the function. I follwed the steps in the link below, but had issues since the syntax seemed to be outdated. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19906473/add-a-marker-on-mouse-click-and-remove-the-existing-on-in-openlayers

Comment: If you onluy need an icon use a vector feature https://codesandbox.io/s/icon-color-forked-ihk8s?file=/main.js

Comment: Thanks @Mike for the help! ill try to implement this. Enjoy the rest of your day/night